# Perform action after TinyMCE rendered in DOM

Tags: tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE 4 and setting it up as follows:

```
tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "specific_textareas",
            editor_selector : "basicTinyMCE",
            theme : "modern",
            readonly : false,
            ...});
```

I want to call a function after it has been rendered in the DOM.

I came across [this](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onPostRender) and tried:

```
tinyMCE.init({
                mode : "specific_textareas",
                editor_selector : "basicTinyMCE",
                theme : "modern",
                readonly : false,
                setup : function(ed) {
                  ed.onPostRender.add(function(ed,cm) {
                    console.log('After render: ' + ed.id);
                  });
                }
              });
```

I get the following error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'add' of undefined or null reference
```

Any ideas if this is the correct way to achieve what I want? 
And if so, why is the error appearing?

Answer (score 6):

You've got two options:

1. Use configuration **init_instance_callback** [http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:init_instance_callback](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3ainit_instance_callback)
2. Use new way to add callbacks

   ed.on('postRender', function(e) {
      console.log('postRender');
   });

Comment: I tried adding the callback as per the second point noted here. But it did not make a difference for me (I found that if I added a timeout of 5 seconds, it did execute the post rendering callback function that I wanted to be called). I hate to explicitly set a timeout on third party js controls, but I ended up doing that as due to asynchronous execution I think the setup functions execute faster and randomly then expected.

Comment: Url for documentation for **init_instance_callback** has become outdated and simply opens general docs section, here is an updated one: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#init_instance_callback

Answer (score 0):

I found the "Dirty" event was what I wanted, only triggered after the user makes a change to the contents of the editor

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/events/