# TinyMCE 4 - Custom HTML inside the SplitButton

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

How can I add custom HTML instead of regular button in TinyMCE 4 inside the split button drop menu?

```
ed.addButton('demo_button', {
            title: 'Demo Button',
            type: 'splitbutton',
            onclick: function() {

            },
            menu: [                 
                {   
                    text : 'Some Regular Button', onclick : function() {

                    }
                },
                {
                    //How to add some custom html for combo box here for example?
                }
            ]
        });
```

In previous version (TinyMCE 3) I was able to use this:

```
var c = cm.createSplitButton('demo_button', {
                title : 'Demo Button',
                onclick : function() {

                }
            });

            c.onRenderMenu.add(function(c, m) {
                m.onShowMenu.add(function(c,m){
                    var $menu = jQuery('#menu_'+c.id+'_co').find('tbody:first');
                    if($menu.data('added')) return;
                    $menu.append('SOME HTML HERE');
                    $menu.data('added',true);
                });
            });
```

So basically my question is how to migrate this piece of code to TinyMCE 4?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

If you were using TinyMCE 3.0 are now migrating to TinyMCE 4+, may be you can first try using their compat3x plugin, which will allow you to transition most of your old plugins without modifications as per their documentation available here:

[TinyMCE compat3x plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:compat3x)

Answer (score 2):

Like you did with the v3, you have to edit the dom after TinyMCE rendering.
To catch rendering process, use `init_instance_callback`

See : http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3ainit_instance_callback

And this SO answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24557748/911718